# How to make pagination with category post Codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, pagination

anybody know how to fix my problem.. 
my problem is for pagination based on category work but when i click button pagination the result is page not found maybe there is something wrong with my routes but i'm not sure about that .. please help me..
this my route

```
$route['blog/category/:any']                 = 'Blog_Category_Post/page';
```

this my controller

```
public function page($offset=0)
{
    $id=$this->uri->segment('3');
    $this->db->select('id,categoryId');
    $this->db->from('t_blog_post');
    $this->db->where('categoryId',$id);
    $query= $this->db->get();

    //$jml                        = $this->db->get('t_blog_post');
    $config['base_url']         = base_url().'blog/category/'.$id.'/page';
    $config['total_rows']       = $query->num_rows();
    $config['per_page']         = 2; /*Jumlah data yang dipanggil perhalaman*/  
    $config['uri_segment']      = 4;    /*data selanjutnya di parse diurisegmen 3*/
    /*Class bootstrap pagination yang digunakan*/
    $config['full_tag_open']    = "<ul class='pagination pagination-sm' style='position:relative; top:-25px;'>";
    $config['full_tag_close']   ="</ul>";
    $config['num_tag_open']     = '<li>';
    $config['num_tag_close']    = '</li>';
    $config['cur_tag_open']     = "<li class='disabled'><li class='active'><a href='#'>";
    $config['cur_tag_close']    = "<span class='sr-only'></span></a></li>";
    $config['next_tag_open']    = "<li>";
    $config['next_tagl_close']  = "</li>";
    $config['prev_tag_open']    = "<li>";
    $config['prev_tagl_close']  = "</li>";
    $config['first_tag_open']   = "<li>";
    $config['first_tagl_close'] = "</li>";
    $config['last_tag_open']    = "<li>";
    $config['last_tagl_close']  = "</li>";
    $this->pagination->initialize($config);

    $list_blogPost=$this->BlogCategory->get_post($config['per_page'], $offset,$id);
    $list_lastblogPost=$this->BlogCategory->get_last_post();
    $list_blogCategory=$this->BlogCategory->get_category();
    $data=array(
        'title'          => 'Blog',
        'userId'         => $this->session->userdata('sh_userId'),
        'fullName'       => $this->session->userdata('sh_fullName'),
        'accountTypeId'  => $this->session->userdata('sh_accountTypeId'),
        'photo'          => $this->session->userdata('sh_photo'),
        'halaman'        => $this->pagination->create_links(),
        'offset'         => $offset,
        'listblogPost'   => $list_blogPost,
        'listlastblogPost'=> $list_lastblogPost,
        'listblogCategory'=>$list_blogCategory
        );
    $this->template->display_admin('blog_categorypost',$data);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As your URL has two params you need to set TWO routes for the method. Change your route as

```
$route['blog/category/(:any)/page'] = 'Blog_Category_Post/page/$1/page';
$route['blog/category/(:any)/page/(:any)'] = 'Blog_Category_Post/page/$1/page/$2';
```

and now change config line `base_url` as following

```
$config['base_url']  = site_url('blog/category').'/'.$id.'/page';
```

finally your `page` controller should be

```
    public function page($categoryId){
     $this->db->select('id,categoryId');
     $this->db->from('t_blog_post');
     $this->db->where('categoryId',$categoryId);
     $query= $this->db->get();

    //$jml                        = $this->db->get('t_blog_post');
     $config['base_url']         = site_url('blog/category/').'/'.$categoryId.'/page';
     $config['total_rows']       = $query->num_rows();
     $config['per_page']         = 2; /*Jumlah data yang dipanggil perhalaman*/  
    $config['uri_segment']      = 5;    /*data selanjutnya di parse diurisegmen 3*/
    /*Class bootstrap pagination yang digunakan*/
     $config['full_tag_open']    = "<ul class='pagination pagination-sm' style='position:relative; top:-25px;'>";
     $config['full_tag_close']   ="</ul>";
     $config['num_tag_open']     = '<li>';
     $config['num_tag_close']    = '</li>';
     $config['cur_tag_open']     = "<li class='disabled'><li class='active'><a href='#'>";
     $config['cur_tag_close']    = "<span class='sr-only'></span></a></li>";
     $config['next_tag_open']    = "<li>";
     $config['next_tagl_close']  = "</li>";
     $config['prev_tag_open']    = "<li>";
     $config['prev_tagl_close']  = "</li>";
     $config['first_tag_open']   = "<li>";
     $config['first_tagl_close'] = "</li>";
     $config['last_tag_open']    = "<li>";
     $config['last_tagl_close']  = "</li>";
     $this->pagination->initialize($config);

    if ($this->uri->segment(5)) {
            $offset = $this->uri->segment(5);
        } else {
            $offset = 0;
        }

     $list_blogPost=$this->BlogCategory->get_post($config['per_page'], $offset,$categoryId);
     $list_lastblogPost=$this->BlogCategory->get_last_post();
     $list_blogCategory=$this->BlogCategory->get_category();
     $data=array(
        'title'          => 'Blog',
        'userId'         => $this->session->userdata('sh_userId'),
        'fullName'       => $this->session->userdata('sh_fullName'),
        'accountTypeId'  => $this->session->userdata('sh_accountTypeId'),
        'photo'          => $this->session->userdata('sh_photo'),
        'halaman'        => $this->pagination->create_links(),
        'offset'         => $offset,
        'listblogPost'   => $list_blogPost,
        'listlastblogPost'=> $list_lastblogPost,
        'listblogCategory'=>$list_blogCategory
        );
     $this->template->display_admin('blog_categorypost',$data);
}
```

Now test.

Comment: thank for you info but actually by script work for pagination filter by category for example
http://localhost/eh/blog/category/1 (id category)
the problem is 
for link pagination is http:/localhost/eh/blog/category/1/page/2(page)
and link pagiination give result 404

Comment: @JefriFernando ok I have updated my answer. now check

Comment: is there change in route or something sir ? actually previous i have type script like your suggest but the result is page not found 404

Comment: up up up up up up

Comment: ?? whats happened

Comment: still give respon page not found because config['site_url'] direcly read my controller and my function not read my route i use $config['site_url']=site_url('blog/category').'/'.$id.'/page'; it's mean i call controller 'blog' function 'category' while i don't have function category in my controller because we use our route

Comment: thank you mr Rejoanul Alam i Have try your code and this code work but my post same like post in page 1 so all page show same page
i think $offset not change i don't know why sir

Comment: so now show your url of second page. Is this URL `http:/localhost/eh/blog/category/1/page/2` showing same result as `http:/localhost/eh/blog/category/1` this page??

Comment: that code already work sir i just need to add
$offset=$this->uri->segment('5');
thanks sir for your helping

Comment: so show how you use `limit()` method in `get_post()` method in `BlogCategory` model

Comment: that code already work sir i just need to add $offset=$this->uri->segment('5'); thanks sir for your helping

Comment: it was in my code. I have revised it as your needs. That means you don't copied my code. however I have processed more technically it in `page` method. Notice belwo of this line `$this->pagination->initialize($config);`